# Cisco callmanager SIP features

Tags: cisco, voip, sip, cisco-voip

I am a programmer working in a software for the sales dept. I would like to know if a feature I want to implement is possible or not.

The user has an application where he can see information about a customer, including the phone number. **My question is:**

- Is it possible, to *send* the phone number to a Cisco CallManager which after receiving the request would call the user's phone and after picking up the phone it would automatically dial the customer's phone number.

I checked the API docs, but honestly, I do not know what I should be looking for, if there is any technical term that describes what I want.

I apologize for the sort of confusing post, but I do not have much knowledge of the technical jargon in this field.

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The term you are looking for to describe this behavior, is an Outbound Campaign.

There is no built in functionality in Cisco Call Manager (CUCM) itself to do this.

However, both of Cisco's Contact Center products do have this ability.  Unified Contact Center Express (UCCX) has a more limited capability for performing a Campaign, but is a much cheaper, much simpler solution to implement.  It is still not cheap or simple though!

For more complicated out dialing ability, you'd want to look into Unified Contact Center Enterprise.  At that point, due to the cost and complexity of UCCE, I'd recommend involving a Cisco Partner to design and implement the system for you.

---

With all of that said, if you were controlling a phone via one of the phone control APIs that Cisco provides, you may be able to rig something up yourself to do this.  It just won't be as neat or integrated as the Cisco solution.

It might work something like this:

- **UserA** indicates to your software that they're ready to make an outbound call to a customer.
- Your software consults the list of customers to call, and sees that **CustomerB** is up next.
- Your software looks up the relevant info of **CustomerB** in it's database (phone number, account number, etc).
- Then, utilizing a Cisco TAPI configuration, your software takes control of **UserA**'s phone.
- Your software makes **UserA**'s phone go off-hook, and initiate a call to the retrieved customer number.
- **UserA** hears ringback on their headset and is now on a call to **CustomerB**, with all of their account info displayed on the screen via your software.

There are many other ways you could go about it, that's just one possibility.  This doesn't give you supervisory ability to only connect the call if a customer answers, but that's part of what the UCCX and UCCE solutions provide.

Comment: Thank you for the very informative answer. Just one more question, Can I run the TAPI server side? Because they are running MACs and I believe TAPI is windows only.

Comment: You could certainly run the TAPI session from the server.  Also if Java is your language of choice they offer JTAPI as well, in order to be platform agnostic.